# How to sequence SQL commands to execute a series of transformations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, powerbi-desktop

I'm used to Powerquery's sequential command structure where each new step references the output of the previous one, like ...

1. Declare source Table1 with columns a, b, c. [RESULT: a, b, c]
2. Calculate some new field x [RESULT: a, b, c, x]
3. Merge (left join) with Table2 [RESULT: a, b, c, x, T2.y]
4. Group by x [RESULT: agg(a), agg(b), agg(c), x, agg(T2.y)]
5. Merge (left join) with Table3 [RESULT: agg(a), agg(b), agg(c), x, agg(T2.y), T3.z]
   etc.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure a series of transformations like the one above.

I'd appreciate any advice, or links to references or helpful hints out there for someone going from PowerBI to SQL.

Comment: Asking for advice isn't an answerable question; see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) We need to know what you *specifically* need help with. As for asking for references and links, such questions are off-topic for [so]. You were prompted to take the [tour] when you signed up (over 4 years ago), but are yet to do so; I suggest you do as it explains what types of questions are likely to be well received and why yours doesn't fit the model.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Larnu. I didn't recall the offer to take the tour -- in fact, I didn't even remember that I had a Stack Overflow account when I stumbled onto some helpful info on the site last week. I'll take the tour today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One simple way is

1. Combining steps 1 and 2. Selecting a,b, and c columns, and then calculating a new column *iseven*.

   ```
   select a,b,c, 
   case when b%2 = 0 then 'even' else 'odd' end iseven, 
   from t1
   ```
2. Left join with t2.

   ```
   select a,b,c, 
   case when b%2 = 0 then 'even' else 'odd' end iseven, 
   [t2.y] y
   from t1
   left join t2 
   on t1.a = t2.y
   ```
3. Using groupby on iseven column and aggregating columns a,b and c. Here we use will wrap the above query in a subquery.

   ```
   select sum(a) sumofA, sum(b) sumofB, sum(c) sumofC, Sum(y) sumOfY 
   from
      (
       select a,b,c, 
       case when b%2 = 0 then 'even' else 'odd' end iseven, 
       t2.z y
       from t1
       left join t2 on t1.a = t2.y
       ) master 
    group by iseven
   ```
4. For the final left join with t3.

   ```
   select sumofA,sumofB,sumofC, t3.Z from 
   (
      select sum(a) sumofA, sum(b) sumofB, sum(c) sumofC, Sum(y) 
      sumOfY 
      from
        (
            select a,b,c, case when b%2 = 0 then 'even' else 'odd' end 
            iseven, t2.z y
            from t1
            left join t2 on t1.a = t2.y
         ) master group by iseven
    ) resultTillstep4 
    left join t4 on resultTillstep4.sumofA = t3.Z
   ```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again, @RishuRanjan. This helped me immeasurably.